# Custom Radio button Onclick Listener

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have a custom dialogue box in which there is two radio button.The two radio button are placed inside Radio group.Whenever I am applying onClickListener to the radio button I am facing an error and my app  get stopped.

**Here is my code-:**

```
    package com.example.user.attendance;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class Fragments extends Fragment {

    Button Register_Cancel_fullname, Register_Cancel_email, Register_Cancel_phone,
            Register_Cancel_password, Sign_up,Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password;
    String  Passcode,Confirm_Passcode;
    EditText Full_Name, Email_Address, Phone_number, Password_register,Confirm_Password_register;
    CircleImageView Register_add_photo;
    LinearLayout select_photo_from_camera,select_photo_from_gallery;
    TextView textView,hint_textview_circular_image_view;
   // RadioButton Category_teacher,Category_student;
    RadioGroup Teacher_student;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myfragmentVieew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);

        //Edit Text
        Full_Name = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_name_and_surname);
        Email_Address = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Email_address);
        Phone_number = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Phone);
        Password_register = (EditText) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Password);
        Confirm_Password_register=(EditText)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                .Confirm_Password_Register);



        //Button
        Sign_up = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Signup);
        Register_Cancel_fullname = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_First_Cancel_Button);
        Register_Cancel_email = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Second_Cancel_Button);
        Register_Cancel_phone = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_Third_Cancel_Button);
        Register_Cancel_password = (Button) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_fourth_Cancel_Button);
        Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password=(Button)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                .Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password_Button);
        Register_add_photo=(CircleImageView)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_add_photo);
        Teacher_student=(RadioGroup)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Category_teacher_student);
        /*Category_student=(RadioButton)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                .Student_category_radio_button);
        Category_teacher=(RadioButton)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                .Teacher_category_radio_button);*/


        //TextView
        textView = (TextView) myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id.Register_textview);
        hint_textview_circular_image_view=(TextView)myfragmentVieew.findViewById(R.id
                .hint_of_image_view);

        /*Setting the Visibility of the Cancel Button*/
        Register_Cancel_fullname.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Register_Cancel_email.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Register_Cancel_phone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Register_Cancel_password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        // Signup Button disabled by default
        Sign_up.setEnabled(false);

        /*IMPLEMENTING TEXT WATCHER*/

        //Full Name
        Full_Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                cancel_button_visibility(Full_Name,Register_Cancel_fullname);
            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                signup_button_enability();
            }
        });

        //Email Id
        Email_Address.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                cancel_button_visibility(Email_Address,Register_Cancel_email);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                signup_button_enability();
            }
        });

        //Phone Number
        Phone_number.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                cancel_button_visibility(Phone_number,Register_Cancel_phone);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                signup_button_enability();
            }
        });

        //Password
        Password_register.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                cancel_button_visibility(Password_register,Register_Cancel_password);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                signup_button_enability();
            }
        });

        //Confirm Password
        Confirm_Password_register.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                cancel_button_visibility(Confirm_Password_register,Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                signup_button_enability();

            }
        });


        /*IMPLEMENTING ONCLICK LISTENER FOR CANCEL BUTTON*/

        cancel_button_visibility_delete(Register_Cancel_fullname, Full_Name);
        cancel_button_visibility_delete(Register_Cancel_email, Email_Address);
        cancel_button_visibility_delete(Register_Cancel_phone, Phone_number);
        cancel_button_visibility_delete(Register_Cancel_password, Password_register);
        cancel_button_visibility_delete(Register_Cancel_Confirm_Password, Confirm_Password_register);

        /*For Onlick Submit Button*/

        Sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //int flag=0;
                int name_flag=0,passcode_flag=0,repasscode_flag=0,email_flag=0,mobile_flag=0;
                Pattern pattern;
                Matcher matcher;
                                               /*NAME PATTERN*/
                String NAME_PATTERN = "" +
                        "[.]+||[aeiou]+||[AEIOU]+||[b-df-hj-nq-tv-z]+||[B-DF-HJ-NQ-TV-Z]+||[0-9" +
                        "]+||[B-DF" +
                        "-HJ-NQ-T]+[AEIOU]+||[b-df-hj-nq-tv-z]+[aeiou]+||[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+||[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+";

                pattern = Pattern.compile(NAME_PATTERN);
                matcher = pattern.matcher(Full_Name.getText().toString().trim());

                      if (matcher.matches() == true) {
                             Full_Name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_border_red);
                             Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim
                            .shake);
                             Full_Name.startAnimation(shake);
                             name_flag=0;
                      }
                      else {
                          name_flag= 1;
                      }

                                              /*EMAIL PATTERN*/

                String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
                pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
                matcher = pattern.matcher(Email_Address.getText().toString().trim());

                      if (matcher.matches() == false) {
                          Email_Address.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_border_red);
                          Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim
                                  .shake);
                          Email_Address.startAnimation(shake);
                          email_flag=0;
                      }
                      else {
                          email_flag = 1;
                      }
                                               /*PHONE PATTERN*/

                String PHONE_PATTERN = "[0]||[1]||[2]||[3]||[4]||[5]||[6]||9{10}||8{10}||7{10}||9{5}0" +
                        "{5}||8{5}0{5}||7{5}0{5}||9{5}1{5}||8{5}1{5}||7{5}1{5}||9{5}2{5}||8{5}2{5}||7{5}2{5" +
                        "}||9{5}3{5}||8{5}3{5}||7{5}3{5}||9{5}4{5}||8{5}4{5}||7{5}4{5}||9{5}5{5}||8{5}5{5" +
                        "}||7{5}5{5}||9{5}6{5}||8{5}6{5}||7{5}6{5}||9{5}7{5}||8{5}7{5}||9{5}8{5}||9{4}||8{4" +
                        "}||7{4}";
                pattern = Pattern.compile(PHONE_PATTERN);
                matcher = pattern.matcher(Phone_number.getText().toString().trim());

                     if (matcher.matches() == true || Phone_number.getText().toString().length()
                        < 10) {
                             Phone_number.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_border_red);
                             Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim
                            .shake);
                            Phone_number.startAnimation(shake);
                            mobile_flag=0;
                     }
                     else {
                         mobile_flag = 1;
                     }
                                         /*PASSWORD VALIDATION*/
                            Passcode = Password_register.getText().toString().trim();
                            Confirm_Passcode = Confirm_Password_register.getText().toString()
                                    .trim();

                     if (Passcode.length()<5) {
                          Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"The passcode should be greater than the 5" +
                                  " digit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          passcode_flag=0;
                     }
                                        /*CHECKING PASSWORD EQUALITY*/

                     if (Passcode.equals(Confirm_Passcode)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "MATCHED",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            repasscode_flag=1;
                     }
                     else {
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UNMATCHED",
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         repasscode_flag=0;
                     }
                     if(name_flag==1 && email_flag==1 && mobile_flag==1 &&
                             repasscode_flag==1){
                         LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                         View promptView2=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout
                                 .custom_dialog_for_category_teacher_student,null);
                         AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                         alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                         alertDialog.setView(promptView2);

                         alertDialog.show();


                     }



            }
        });
        Teacher_student.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                if(i==R.id.Radio_button_teacher)
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



                Register_add_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                      public void onClick(View view) {
                       LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                       View promptView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog,null);

                         final AlertDialog builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                        builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                        select_photo_from_camera=(LinearLayout) promptView.findViewById(R.id
                        .Select_photo_from_Camera);
                        select_photo_from_gallery=(LinearLayout)promptView.findViewById(R.id
                                .Select_photo_from_gallery);
                         builder.setView(promptView);
                         select_photo_from_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                       @Override
                          public void onClick(View view) {
                             Intent cameraintent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                             int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST=1;
                             startActivityForResult(cameraintent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);



                          }
                      });



                         select_photo_from_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(View view) {
                                 int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST=0;
                                 Intent intent=new Intent();
                                 intent.setType("image/*");
                                 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select picture"),
                                         PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

                             }
                         });

                               builder.show();
                   }
                });
        return myfragmentVieew;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

                /*if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    hint_textview_circular_image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Register_add_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }*/
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // address of the image
            Uri selectedImages=data.getData();
            //declare a stream to read the image data from the "selectedimages"
            InputStream inputStream;

            try {
                inputStream=getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImages);

                Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                Register_add_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                hint_textview_circular_image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");



        }
        }

    void signup_button_enability() {
        if (Full_Name.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && Email_Address.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 &&
                Phone_number.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && Password_register
                .getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && Confirm_Password_register.getText()
                .toString().trim().length()>0) {
            Sign_up.setEnabled(true);

        } else {
            Sign_up.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void cancel_button_visibility_delete(Button cancel, final EditText editText) {
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
    public void cancel_button_visibility(EditText editText,Button button){
        if(editText.getText().toString().length()>0)
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

**The custom dialog xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_dialog">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHOOSE YOUR CATEGORY"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/hint_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/view"></View>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEACHER"
        android:layout_marginTop="53sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="STUDENT"
        android:layout_marginTop="95sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/Category_teacher_student"

        >
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Teacher_category_radio_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/hint_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/Student_category_radio_button"/>
    </RadioGroup>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**The logcat is showing this:**

```
  Process: com.example.user.attendance, PID: 15344
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.user.attendance.Fragments.onCreateView(Fragments.java:336)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7402)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I even tried to use onClickListener to the radio button but same error is showing.

Comment: Where is **`findViewById`** of your `Teacher_student` RadioGroup

Comment: inside the class

Comment: **Teacher_student** is null ?

Comment: how Teacher_student null.I have declared Teacher_student inside the class of the fragment activity.@0ddlyoko

Comment: Put your whole activity code that will give clear idea.

Comment: can you post full code related to that radio group

Comment: Use Radio Button Control setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) for this and check & then check it's id inside their onCheckedChanged() method. Radio group will do their work for single selection behaviour

and yes your both radio button must be not null.

Comment: I have tried but not working-@SameerJani

Comment: Hello @zarrarkhan, Can you please share your fragment code inside this? So I can help you in proper way.https://codeshare.io/zarrarkhan

Comment: I have found my solution.....Thanks for your answer all of you guys...